# Delphi FMX LiveBindings Rectangle.Fill.Color from a Database Field

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, livebindings

I need to assign a TRectangle.Fill.Color from a database field using LiveBindings, it looks like a simple thing, but I could not do it.  Maybe the field type, maybe the value, but when assigned from a PrototypedBinding...it works.

How can I assign a color using livebindings?

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: I've had no problem binding visually `LONGWORD` field of an SQLite table I've created using FireDAC in Tokyo. Could you elaborate in details what's the exact problem, please?

Comment: I want a TRectangle.Fill.Color change based on a value in a field from database table, so when I change the record...the color changes the TRectabgle.

Comment: I understand. That's exactly what I was able to do. I'm asking what you're having trouble with. I've binded to persistent field through `TLinkPropertyToField`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working example of what you need:

The field type is `LongWord` because `System.UITypes` declares `TAlphaColor = type Cardinal` and both `Cardinal` and `LongWord` are aliases for `UInt32`.

Watch the values generated by `PrototypeBindSource` (on the right):
[image]

Check if the values from your database correspond to the unsigned integer values representing the required colors. Maybe you tried too small values?

And here is a pattern of bindings for the given form:
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, Now to try it out!